# (node js) Utilities for comparing results of globbing patterns

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, glob

Suppose I have the following variables:

```
var pathA = '/dirA/dirB/**/*.html';
var pathB = '/dirA/**/**';
var pathC = '/dirA/dirB/dirC/file.html';
```

I want to be able to check which of these variables consumes the others.  (So for example, pathC, would be in the matched results of both pathA and pathB.  And all the files that would match from the pathA glob, would also match in pathB glob, but not vice versa).

Does anyone know of any good npm utility library which provides this functionality to check these things?  (Without actually getting the results of the glob matching and exhaustively comparing the results).  I figure there should be some clever way that's already implemented, just by looking at the string itself.

Comment: https://github.com/IonicaBizau/node-is-there maybe this can help you :/

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I think this does not accept globs.  More than that, it's not about actually verifying what's on the filesystem, rather just analyzing the globs themselves.  (For example, instead of processing both globs pathA and pathB, I want to check first if one is a superset of the other, and only expand on that one.)